# React-Native error setState used in arrow function

Tags: react-native

I know was a thousand such questions relating to this same issue, but I've already exhausted ideas what might cause it in my case :/

I'm trying to update variable when after getting response from API.
I already changed all functions to use arrow function but I keep getting this error:
`this.setState is not a function`
and I can't find error in my code.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

app/routes/users/login/view.js

```
const UsersLoginView = (props) => {
  let email = '';

  this.state = {
    textError: '',
    inputError: false,
  }

  login = (event) => {
    device_info = {
      UUID: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
      brand: DeviceInfo.getBrand(),
      model: DeviceInfo.getModel(),
      system: DeviceInfo.getSystemName(),
      system_version: DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion(),
      timezone: DeviceInfo.getTimezone(),
      locale: DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale(),
    }

    fetch("my url", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        device: device_info
      })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        textError: 'SUCCESS',
        inputError: false
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({
        textError: error.message,
        inputError: true
      });
    })
    .done();
  },

  updateEmail = (text) => {
    email = text
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
          User
        </Text>
        <Form>
          <Item error={this.state.inputError}>
            <Icon active name='ios-at-outline' />
            <Input
              autoCorrect={false}
              placeholder='E-mail'
              returnKeyType='go'
              keyboardType='email-address'
              autoCapitalize='none'
              onChangeText = { (text) => updateEmail(text) }
            />
          </Item>
          <Text>{this.state.textError}</Text>
              <Button full light style={{marginTop: 20}} onPress={ () => login }>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default UsersLoginView;
```

app/routes/users/login/index.js

```
import UsersLoginView from './view';

class UsersLogin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <UsersLoginView />
    );
  }
}

export default UsersLogin;
```

maybe login function should be in index.js file then I will have access to state ?

Comment: May I ask why you are using a Functional Component instead of Class Components?

Comment: Check this out to help with refactoring to a Class Component https://snack.expo.io/SJqA-EbSZ

Comment: Due to the structure of the project :/ I update my question maybe now will be more clear..

Comment: what's the difference between the UserLogin and UsersLoginView?

Comment: It's more about separating the view into a separate file

Answer (score 0):

The error is here: `const UsersLoginView = (props) => {`, you need to use a class if you want to maintain state.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked if there was a reason he was using functional components instead of Class Components. You should refactor to using a Class Component @m1l05z

Comment: Such a design pattern was adopted based on some example..
@ChiamakaNwolisa Nwolisa Is it possible to pass values from the input form in view file view.js to class component file index.js ?

Comment: Nope, it's not possible. You can only pass props from parent to child and in your case, the parent is `UsersLogin` and the child is `UsersLoginView`

Comment: I moved code from UsersLoginView to UsersLogin and now everything works like charm @ChiamakaNwolisa really thanks for your explanation :)